# bcrypt is crashing the app while generating salt or hashed password

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

As per the bcrypt npm documentation I tried to incorporate the package but unable to use bcrypt package in my app, so to test the bcrypt separately I created sample js file which is also crashing on execution without giving any error. Below is the js file which I tried to test. I tried to pass the constant value to hash function, which is also not working.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
async function run(){
const saltValue =await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
bcrypt.hash('12345',saltValue)
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
}
run();
```

Version:
node : 9.0.0
npm: '5.5.1'
"bcrypt": "^3.0.2",

With nodemon, I am getting message: app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
in normal execution it is not showing any error.

**Update:**

If change the bcrypt's async methods with synchronous then it is working fine,

```
    const saltValue = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hashed = bcrypt.hashSync('12345',saltValue);
```

I think someone from bcrypt team can answer.

**Update**: This issue raised on the community and few other developers are facing the same issue, for more information you can refer the link.

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/674

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... As i have mentioned in the question it is crashing without giving any error:

Comment: If I execute it with node then it crashed without showing any error or any message like app crashed.

Comment: If there's no error then it completed it's execution. Node will exit after running a file.

Comment: I know, but I am not getting any output and the message is also showing app crashed. If I comment the two lines which are using bcrypt then the function is executing without crashing application.

Comment: Shouldn't there be curly braces around your console logs? Sorry it's been awhile since I've used promises like that. I've switched over to async/await with try/catch for promises.

Comment: @Darkrum [that's not necessary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax)

Comment: @Darkrum .. it is an arrow function.

Comment: I don't know why this question is downrated.

Comment: Yes I understand it's a arrow function. Could you switch your hash to use await with a try catch?

Comment: @Darkrum.. I tried that also, even with the await (ing) on this. but no luck.

Comment: What about the genSalt? It's await but you have no try catch on it.

Comment: @Darkrum. that is also not giving any error in the catch block.

Comment: If you switch hash to await and you use console.log on the returned value what do you see? Also if you console.log saltValue what does it show you?

Comment: @Darkrum.. nothing is showing on the console.

Comment: Okay somethings weird then because it should console.log something. Can you do console.log("testing") throughout your file to follow it's execution.

Comment: @Darkrum, I was also doubting this, but console.log("testing") is working fine.

Comment: Facing the same issue on Windows. My app crashes on `bcrypt.hash` but I do not get any error message. It just crashes. Will give bcrypt.js a try.

Comment: @FrankRoth : you can try the synchronous method they should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

bcrypt can be funky sometimes... replace with [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) (far more popular anyway...)

This works just fine:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

async function run() {
  const saltValue = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  bcrypt
    .hash('12345', saltValue)
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
run();
```

Comment: I think node.bcrypt.js and bcryptjs are two different packages.

Comment: There are a bunch... Which one are you using specifically? Can you link to the npm package here?

Comment: @ironman they are but they accomplish the same thing. bcryptjs is just pure JavaScript implementation. No dependencies like the one your using.

Comment: @ironman yes we know but Sakobu is right bcrypt does have issues across different platforms because it is complied. Memory serves me I was having issues with it when working on a raspberry pi so I used the pure JavaScript library instead.

Comment: @SakoBu.. I think it might be related to the latest build of bcrypt package, on my machine it is working fine for synchronous methods but not for asynchronous.

Comment: Recommending another library when the other one should just be working fine is not an answer to the problem.

Comment: @mhombach -- purist views aside, this answer is exactly what I was looking for right now after being stuck for an hour with the package failing as in the OP. This answer is brilliant because it actually solves the problem I'm having -- not being able to hash passwords -- rather than leaving me suffering and pushing the responsibility on someone else.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer BcryptJS was not updated for more than 4 years. It is more insecure and less performant than bcrypt. Also the solution for fixing a bug is not to switch to another library that has majow drawbacks. We just fixed our problem a few days a go and this here was the solution: https://github.com/disney/meteor-base/issues/18#issuecomment-516524883

Basically, for our docker-image, we needed to add a parameter, so a new version for bcrypt is compiled. See if that helps you too, so i can post this as an answer to the original question here. thx in advance :)

Comment: @mhombach -- that won't work for my environment. On my laptop (local dev) I run a custom alpine/nodejs 'wrapper' container that mounts the source directory for the microservice (running the main.js with nodemon). This lets me make changes to my code and have it instantly reloaded. I currently have about 6 microservices that I run-up in a single compose cluster using the same image. Sometimes I stop all the containers and run the service directly in visual studio (in wsl2) so that I can debug the code with breakpoints. The service sometimes runs in alpine and sometimes wsl/ubuntu/windows.

Comment: I'd love to use a more up-to-date version of bcrypt, so maybe I should use a different container if it's a musl-libc issue. Or maybe I should bite the bullet and outsource the jwt piece to Hashicorp Vault.

Answer (score 0):

I have node v8.11.4 and bcrypt 4.0.1 version.

I got same error

> **[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..**.

**My solution:**

I did install bcrypt old version.

```
npm i --save --save-exact bcrypt@2.0.1
```

It works fine

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem, and for me all I needed to do was uninstall and reinstall bcrypt.

```
npm uninstall bcrypt

npm install bcrypt
```

I'm guessing it somehow got corrupted, so reinstalling it recompiled it, fixing whatever was wrong